# MySQL: display first of each group from a specific order

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables fields and content table that look something like this (simplified).

`fields` Table

```
id    name
1     Field One
2     Field Two
```

`content` Table

```
id   field_id   status      content
1    1          draft       xxx
2    1          published   xxx
3    2          published   xxx
```

The only catchy thing is that the content associated to a field has a "draft" system that is independent for each field.

So I retrieve the draft version of all fields, it should bring all the draft except from the field doesn't have a draft version, in that case it should return the published one.

(There are more states, I'm just using two to keep it simple). So, when retrieving from the example table. The result should be something like this:

```
id   field_id   status      content
1    1          draft       xxx
3    2          published   xxx
```

Something that would achieve what I want is this

```
SELECT * FROM contents c1 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM contents c 
       WHERE (c.status = 'draft' OR c.status = 'published') 
            AND c.field_id = c1.field_id 
       ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'draft', 'published') LIMIT 1
);
```

With the only issue that MySQL Version I'm using (5.7.12) doesn't seem to support the limit in an `IN` where.

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

Comment: Do you want to retrieve latest draft (if not present, published) for each field_id?

Comment: That's right GurV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get latest draft (if not present, latest published), you can use user variables to generate partitioned row number (partitioned based on field_id) with required order:

```
select *
from (
select t.*,
    @rn :=  if(@field_id = field_id, 
                @rn + 1,
                if(@field_id := field_id, 1, 1)
                ) rn
from (
    select
    from content
    order by field_id,
        field(status, 'draft', 'published'),
        id desc
    ) t cross join (select @rn := 0, @field_id := -1) t2
) t where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Here is one method that uses aggregation and `max(field())` to identify the appropriate version:

```
select c.*
from (select field_id, min(field(status, 'draft', 'published')) as min_field
      from contents
      group by field_id
     ) cf join
     contents c
     on c.field_id = cf.field_id and field(status, 'draft', 'published') = cf.min_field;
```